# Change color on elements overlap

Tags: react-native, jsx

i'm trying to change a color when two elements overlap.
Here's an example image below:

[image: toolbar]

When the white button slides over, i would like to change the icon's color to blue from white. How can i achieve that?

Edit: I guess i should have been more explicit. The switch button is moving and when it goes halfway through the icon, i would like that half of the icon to be blue, it doesn't help to change it after the button is over the icon, because that would just pop it in there and you wouldn't see the icon until it's fully switched.
So what i'm asking is if you can overlap and when it's overlapping, to change the color of it.

Answer (score 1):

In your style you can put something like this: `style={{color: (this.state.isSelected) ? "blue" : "white"}}` it of course depends on how you control the switch and which color you want. This is called ternary operator in JavaScript, you can find more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Not what i was going for, i need to change the colors midway, not after the switch is toggled. Thanks for the suggestion though